# How to Unhide an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, show-hide

Need a little bit of help here ....  I am using auto populated dropdowns. the second dropdown only appears after an item is selected in the first dropdown - however, i want this to remain on the screen and not disappear on a page reload, as if i want to search another town, i cant as the second one only appear after selecting the first (if you know what i mean)...

Heres My jQ...
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#wait_1').hide();
$('#result_1').show();
$('#drop_1').change(function(){
  $('#wait_1').show();
      $.get("twotier/func.php", {
    func: "drop_1",
    drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
  }, function(response){

    $('#result_1').fadeIn();
    setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
  });
    return false;
});
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
$('#wait_1').hide();
$('#'+id).html(unescape(response));

}
```

...AND MY HTML

//gets the main counties

```
<select name="drop_1" class="searchboxes" id="drop_1">
 <option value="" selected="selected">Any Town</option>
 <?php getTierOne(); echo $drop_var; ?>
 </select>
```

///waiting images fades in and out upon response

```
 <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;"><img alt="Please Wait" src="twotier/ajax-           loader.gif"/></span>
```

// shows the towns dropdown

```
 <span id="result_1"></span>
```

I can see where it is fading in, but don't know how to stop it doing that, ive been trying for hours. I just need it always available (so if i select East Midlands, then Derby and view the results, i can then select Leicester without having to select and deselect Midlands again as currently the towns drop down disappears on page reload.)

hoping someone can help me here. thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to show the dropdown_2 if it has some values in it after page reload even the drop_1 is not changed. Is that right??

Comment: Hiya. Yes. One page load, only the Counties show, the towns only shows when Counties is changed, this is not ideal, as in if i choose a countty, then a town, when I click submit, the towns drop down vanishes and I cant get it back without selecting the Counties again, which is very annoying lol. I just need it to always show (but of course still update the towns list when the county is changed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for default value in towns drop down on page load. If default is there, then hide the dropdown else show it.

You need to have some thing like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(('#drop2').val() !== 'default'){
      // show drop 2   
    }else{
        //hide drop 2   
    }
});
```